# Recharts - "point" scale makes BarChart XAxis overflow

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to use XAxis with scale="point" but I noticed that there are two issues:

1. The bars overflow
2. On hover, the vertical line is missing

Here is my code:

```
<BarChart
    width={500}
    height={300}
    data={data}
    margin={{
      top: 5,
      right: 30,
      left: 20,
      bottom: 5,
    }}
  >
   <XAxis dataKey="uv" fontSize={10} scale="point" />
   <YAxis />
   <Legend />
   <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
   <Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8" />
</BarChart>
```

[image]

Do you know what this is happening? I don't want to use the default scale="auto".

Here is a reproducable example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-kowalevski-23mzy6?file=/src/App.js:82,42
Thanks!